# Replace old number-based captcha to the new nocaptcha on data.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, captcha

As it's in the title. Should replace the old captcha where you need to enter numbers to Google's new one-click captcha, just like on all human verification pages that you see when you search.

Comment: More appropriate on MSE since data.SE is network wide?

Comment: [They accept PR, just fix it ;)](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)

Answer (score 4):

reCAPTCHA v1 is [going away at the end of the month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305988/recaptcha-v1-is-shutting-down-on-march-31-but-sede-still-uses-it), which has resulted in this finally being completed